# How to exit a simplegui frame in codeskulptor?

Tags: python, codeskulptor

I am making a pong game in code skulptor, i have created an exit game button, but i need some sort of function to exit the whole entire game. The pong game is complete and this is the only feature left, thanks for all the help in advance as i'm rather new to python :)

Comment: Could you please include some evidence of having attempted this on your own?

Answer (score 1):

With the `Frame.stop()` function.
I don't know why this function is *not* in the *CodeSkulptor* documentation.
I added it to my documentation of the *SimpleGUICS2Pygame* package:
[`Frame.stop()`](https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpleguics2pygame/frame.html#SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame.frame.Frame.stop)

If you have active timers, don't forget to stop them with the [`Timer.stop()`](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#timer-stop) function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `exit()`. It's compatible with both Codeskulptor and normal Python so you can implement it in other programs in and out of Codeskulptor too.